# Nvm persist node version for current login ubuntu session

Tags: node.js, nvm

Problem: 
Whenever I open a new terminal, nvm uses `version 4.4` which is default.
I am trying new features like `async await`, I have installed `Node 8` for these playgrounds. I have to switch everytime back to 8 whenever I start a new shell.

Can there be a possible way to persist node version for current login session, I don't want to set 8 as default either.

Comment: I guess it starts by defining what you mean by "current session".

Comment: my bad, i mean current login session

Answer (score 0):

(nvm maintainer here)

The default is set based on either an `.nvmrc` file in the current directory, or anywhere up to `/` - or, the `default` alias.

You can have multiple effective defaults if you're comfortable with doing it on a per-directory-tree basis.

Separately from that, "persist the node version across shell sessions" is the same thing as "set the default" - so either the default has to be 4, or 8, in your scenario.

Comment: I will give it a try first. :)